# split screen works seperately

Tags: mirror

I want to work separately on my split screens. On one screen I want to use euler rotation and on another screen i want to use axis angle rotation. is it possible? [image]

Comment: pls don't write in capital letters because this might be considered as rude or shouting. thx.

Comment: As long as it is the same object - nope.